# How to hide the label text when the value is empty?

Tags: angularjs

Within a table cell, I am listing several items that are populated using ng-repeat, using the structure below. However, for some entries, properties such as "user.favcolor" are blank. What's the easiest way to hide text such as "Favorite color:" in that case so that I don't end up with a row that has "Favorite color:" and no value beside it?

```
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Plan Contents</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="tip in tips">
                    <td>{{tip.priceMonthly}}</td>
                    <td><span>Name: {{user.name}}</span>
                        <span>ID: {{user.id}}</span>
                        <span>Favorite color: {{user.favcolor}}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the [`ng-show`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow) directive for this:

```
<span ng-show="user.favcolor">Favorite color: {{user.favcolor}}</span>
```

The `ng-show` works such that the element is only shown if the expression evaluates to `true`. An empty string here will evaluate to `false` hiding the entire element.

Alternatively, you can also specify a default value:

```
<span>Favorite color: {{user.favcolor || "Not specified" }}</span>
```

In this case, if `user.favcolor` evaluates to a `false`, it will print `Not specified` instead.